# Inline Block Span Text Alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Really struggling here aligning some text.

I'm trying to keep this text in one line but in order to set a width to part of the text and hide over flow I had to set the span to *display: inline-block* this is causing issues with alignment. as pictured below:

[image]

**css**

```
.banner {
    top: 65px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}

.description {
    width: 60vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="banner alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" *ngIf="show">
  <a href="#" class="alert-link">4H Incident In Production</a>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" (click)="dismiss()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let incident of incidents">
    <div>
      <b>{{incident.number}}</b>
      <span class="description">{{incident.description}}</span>
      <a href="#" class="alert-link">Click Here For More Information</a>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the incident.description need to be a span?
I would wrap both the incident number and description in a p tag to at least ensure the same margin etc apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you'll likely want to add some spacing between the words, but to just fix your alignment issue you can add `display: flex` to the div that contains the 3 text elements.

It looks like you're using bootstrap, so you can use `class="d-flex"`

```css
.banner {
    top: 65px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}

p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.description {
    width: 60vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="banner alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" *ngIf="show">
  <a href="#" class="alert-link">4H Incident In Production</a>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" (click)="dismiss()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let incident of incidents">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <b>{{incident.number}}</b>
      <span class="description">{{incident.description}}</span>
      <a href="#" class="alert-link">Click Here For More Information</a>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: beautiful, simple, elegant

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `vertical-align` (on the description class)

```
vertical-align: baseline;
vertical-align: sub;
vertical-align: super;
vertical-align: text-top;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
vertical-align: middle;
vertical-align: top;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align